# BrowserStack testing multiple versions of Chrome and Firefox

Tags: testing, browser, google-analytics, cross-browser, web-analytics

In terms of improving efficiency in BrowserStack by eliminating testing multiple versions of the same Browser. I am basing my testing off Google Analytics top 10 most viewed browsers.

If chrome version 30 to 43 is being used, how much do they differ and how what versions should I be testing to be safe? or is it good practise to just be testing on all versions listed in analytics?

The reason I ask is because we have so many different versions of chrome, firefox etc but when I am running test on all the different versions using the same URL, there is not much difference at all, the only difference between all versions of firefox was some versions showed a different GUI arrow on my dropdown forms.

That did not prevent the functionality of the form though.

Thought I would raise this as it might not be ideal to test all versions?

Comment: This all depends pretty much on what level of “playing it safe” you need. With Chrome I personally would definitively not test down to a v30, since Chrome is auto-updating without leaving the normal user much say in the matter – so I’d say we can assume anyone using Chrome will almost always have a quite up-to-date version. Firefox offers a much more easily accessible opt-out of automatic updates; […]

Comment: […] but again I would assume that John/Jane Doe _do_ let it update itself automatically, and whoever deliberately chooses to use an older version should be used to seeing the occasional ”glitch” on websites. To be safe, I’d probably test _one_ version number a few numbers back, but not all of them _in between_ to the newest one; assuming/hoping with fingers crossed, that they only _improve_ things, and not make them worse.

Comment: That was my exact thoughts with Chrome, in regards to Firefox, most used version is version 33.0 then 39, then 40, then 36 etc so it is random, but the difference when I tested 1 page on all versions so only the GUI arrows on drop down fields, everything else seem to behave as expected

Comment: And when using “newer” features that specifically give you reason to doubt browser support, I would check caniuse.com and the MDN for when browsers started to support them, and then maybe explicitly check a specific version one below that, to see if the site still works or if something actually breaks.